# With Facebook API, is it possible to find pages that have a certain range of 'likes'?

Tags: facebook, api

For example, I'd like to find Facebook pages that have between 500 and 1000 likes. Anything more than 1000 or less than 500, I do not want.

Also, it would be ideal to filter these pages by geographic region (city), but I imagine that is easier than the original question.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this does not look easily possible.  FQL doesn't have a count function.  One very resource intensive way to attempt this could be to iterate through pages, fetch the list of likes, and then count them in code.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I don't mind about the counting in code part, I was just curious if someone knew if this was obviously possible or not to at least grab that information.

Comment: Matthew is correct, there is no API which allows you to search Pages by like count. Places (i.e pages with an address) can be queried by location, if that's any help - this is documented on the home page of the graph api documentation